# PowerQuery: "for" loop over all elements

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a structurised json file, containing a list of elements.
I would like to convert all of the elements (which have also a structure) to table format. I can manually do it from PowerQuery GUI for one element; example code below.

```
let
    Source= 
Json.Document(Web.Contents("<source_address>")),
    elements = Source[elements],
    elements1 = elements{0},
    #"Converted into table" = Record.ToTable(elements1)
in
    #"Converted into table"
```

I'd like to iterate through all elements (so from elements{0} to elements{x}) and keep them in one excel output table. All elements have the same structure (columns)

Comment: Are you able to include some sample JSON?

Comment: @chillin let's say the source is here https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static

and more specifically: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/elements/

Comment: I think I was right in my assumptions. Test my answer if you want, I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful to see some sample JSON, as it's difficult to say with certainty without looking at its structure. I've just used some dummy JSON string, which I'm assuming resembles yours (in terms of structure).

```
let
    //Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("<source_address>")),
    Source = Json.Document("{""elements"": [{""someKey1"": ""someValue1""}, {""someKey2"": ""someValue2""}], ""someOtherKey"": ""cat""}"),
    elements = Source[elements],
    transformList = List.Transform(elements, Record.ToTable),
    appended = Table.Combine(transformList)
in
    appended
```

If you copy-paste the above to the `Advanced Editor`, replace the second `Source = ...` with the one from your original code, you can then check if it gives you what you're after.

---

**Edit:**

I think given the URL you've provided, the code below will save you pivoting the table later and give you desired output.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static")),
    elements = Source[elements],
    toTable = Table.FromRecords(elements)
in
    toTable
```

Which gives me the below:

[image: Output]

Comment: I moved forward with Your assumption,
now I only need pivot/unpivot the data (cause I have a Name-Value table, where Name is the column name and Value is a column name parameter value); can I do this with PowerQuery or should I use standard excel pivoting?

Comment: @golazo, yes, you can do this in Power Query. But depends on what end result you want to achieve. Have a look at my edit if you want.

Comment: this each Table.FromRecords(_) was very tricky and exactly what wanted to do; thanks a lot!

Comment: I just realised the last two lines in my edit were totally unnecessary. `elements` is already a list of records, so can be fed directly to `Table.FromRecords` (I don't know why I didn't just do this the first time). It doesn't affect your end result, but I have reduced the code in my edit.